# Integration with Office 2007 VBA and Visual SourceSafe

Tags: vba, visual-sourcesafe, office-2007

I'm wondering if there's a way to manage VBA code authored in Excel 2007 using Visual SourceSafe? Office XP and 2000 apparently had 'developer additions' that supported this (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164419(office.10).aspx). Is this support missing in Office 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office XP VSS addin worked fine in Excel 2007 last time I tried it (been a couple of years). It's really a VBA addin, and VBA hasn't changed much since Excel 2000 (eg, registered addins work across versions). You might need an MSDN subscription to download it, though- that's where I got it.